# Does R2 (R square) of 100% means over fitting in machine learning?

Tags: r-squared

( Its an Interview Question.) Is there a straight yes/no type of answer? Or this should be answered more diplomatic way?
Kindly help!

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just 
posting homework or interview questions is grounds for closing.